# How can I disable the “The app Chrome has requested a certificate” on Android Devices

Tags: android, popup, certificate, x509

Is there anyway I can disable the popup on my Android Device so that when i go to a site and it has cert authentication enabled it will not prompt for me for a cert unless I have one in my keystore?

This seems to be only Android because I also have an iPhone and it does not prompt me .. instead it goes to an email and password logon page instead.

[image: so]

Comment: Why have you added iPhone to your tags?

Comment: i removed iPhone to not upset you any further